# Inserting an <h1> tag with affecting font

Tags: html-heading

```
<p style="margin-left: 14" class="style19"><b>
<font size="6" color="#001E5A" face="Arial">401K Rollover and 
Retirement Planning Center</font></b>
```

Where do I add the `<h1>` and `</h1>` tags without affecting the font or other characteristics?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: everytime I try to add <h1> and </h1> tags it screws up font etc..

Comment: Could you please show the markup that *doesn't* work instead of the one that does.

Comment: I just don't know where to put the tags. I have tried everywhere.

Comment: <p style="margin-left: 14" class="style19"><b>
<font size="6" color="#001E5A" face="Arial"><h1>401K Rollover and 
Retirement Planning Center</h1></font></b>

Comment: this way screws up the page

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using markup for styling - use CSS for that, like:

**Markup:**

```
<h1> 401K Rollover and Retirement Planning Center</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
  font-size: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Here it is the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/9aMpz/)

You can embed the CSS code either in a `<style type="text/css">`tag, or in an external file, you would refer to as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/someStyleSheet.css">
```

Anyway, search for some recent web development guidelines online in order to get a better clue on the topic.